# How I change the sentence of active form to the passive form?

Tags: grammar, past-simple

> - [1] *  I gave him a advice-------- >  active form
>     How Ichange it to the passive form

Can I change it like:

> - [1] *he was given a advice by me.

Comment: The correct passive is: He was given advice by me. Period. End of story.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the word *advice* is always an uncountable noun in English which means that, practically speaking, you never see an indefinite article in front of it:

> I gave him **advice**. / I gave him **some advice**.

If you want to quantify it, here's how you say it:

> I gave him **a piece of advice**.

Now back to the question proper. You are spot on for the most part. The subject of the sentence and the object of the verb need to switch places if you want your sentence to be a passive voice sentence:

> He was given advice by me.

However, while technically correct, there is still a minor problem with this sentence—it's not very idiomatic. *"He received advice from me."* would sound a lot better than *"He was given advice by me."* In the latter example, it sounds like you want to make it clear to the listener that the advice came from you (you were the source of it) as opposed to somebody else—him, her or them (or something to that effect). I don't think that's what you intended to say. It's better to use the verb *receive* when describing a situation where you get or receive something from someone (notice that in this case, the sentence is no longer in the passive voice):

> He **received advice from** me. / He **received a piece of advice from** me.

If there is no need to specify the fact that the advice came from you, then you can certainly say *was given*:

> He **was given advice**. / He **was given a piece of advice**.

Comment: Are you certain that *He received advice from me* is passive? I would expect *My advice was received by him* to be passive.

Comment: It's uncommon, but you can find expressions like "I was given advice" but it would be "by <someone>" more likely than "from".

Comment: @Davo No, I never said that it was a passive voice construction. I said that if you want to use *from*, then it's better to use the verb *receive*. I'll clarify that.

Comment: Why not by: He was given advice by me.?

Comment: @Lambie I know what you mean. With **advice by someone**, the emphasis is on the authorship of the advice rather than on the act of receiving it directly from the source. This is like saying I have a book by John Smith. The book was written by John Smith, but I didn't receive it directly from him.

Comment: I heard "**an advice**" used go refer to a certain piece of advice that is unique or special like in, "**Oh, that was such an advice you gave me yesterday**".

Comment: @SovereignSun Maybe, but most grammar books would definitely advise against saying **an advice**. And I don't think it's even natural to say that.

Comment: @SovereignSun  You can throw out the an.:) That was such good advice you gave me yesterday. Like news: let me give you a piece of advice.

Comment: @CookieMonster ***He gave me advice*** is simply ***I was given advice by him*** in passive form. A passive is technically with by and the agent and not from and the agent. He was given advice from me sounds once-removed. :)

Comment: @Lambie **He was given advice by me** sounds like awkward English, wouldn't you say?

Comment: @CookieMonster Not at all. /He was given advice from me/ sounds like you are talking to someone else, a third party and is slightly different. Actual passive is with by. I gave him advice. Advice was given to him by me.

Comment: @Lambie I don't know why, but **He received advice from me.** sounds a lot better than **He was given advice by me.** In the latter example, it sounds like you really want to make it clear to the listener that the advice came from me (you were the source of it) as opposed to somebody else. Not from him, not from her, but from me.

Comment: @CookieMonster The question is about the passive voice. Not what sounds good.  How many times must one repeat what is a basic thing? A rule in this case for passive is a rule. There is no doubt about it.  Your answer is technically wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly notice that "**advice**" is uncountable, thus comes without an article. You should say "**a piece of advice**" to quantify "*advice*".

> - I gave him a piece of advice.

As for the passive, the correct is:

- A piece of advice was given to him (by me).

I'm not a native speaker but to me "**He was given a piece of advice (by me)**" sounds worse than the option I give.